# Determine available memory that can be used before OutOfMemoryException is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, out-of-memory

The `OutOfMemoryException` for my applications is thrown way before the system itself runs out of memory, as explained by:
[MSDN Blogs  - Out of memory? Easy ways to increase the memory available to your program.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/calvin_hsia/archive/2010/09/27/10068359.aspx)

> When you run your C# application, you might get an `OutOfMemoryException` thrown, even if your  machine has lots of  memory. [...] That 4 Gigs is divided into half: the user application gets the lower half and the OS gets the upper. (This boundary can be changed: see below).

By request, I need to visualize how much memory is available for my application and the current usage. Current usage can be retrieved using `Process.GetCurrentProcess();` and others, but how to determine the memory available to my application at run-time? I just cannot figure out.

Comment: Try out the [CLR Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx)

Comment: There is by default a maximum amount of memory a single process can take to itself, I'm pretty sure its 1GB on Windows. Of course you can use more, but I can't help you on how to do that.

Comment: No the address space is 2GB on x86

Comment: In any case you are pretty much limited if you application is 32 bits.

Comment: Post your code and people can help you optimize it, if you like to

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) to check before a large allocation.  This isn't exactly what you're asking for, but if your failure is at a particular known large allocation point, this at least allows you to cleanly handle the allocation failure at the point that it occurs.